# Does anyone have ELMAH working with SharePoint?

Tags: debugging, elmah

Does anyone have [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) working with SharePoint 2010? I have the assembly in the bin folder and have what I believe to be the correct entries in the web.config file. I can run the test at http://localhost/elmah.axd/test and generate the test error and can display the error reporting page at http://localhost/elmah.axd but it does not show any errors. I have ELMAH currently configured to retain errors in memory. There was mention in an article about the order of elements in httpModules which I have verified. The site is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 with SharePoint 2010 Foundation and IIS 7. Below are the entries from my web.config:

```
   <configSections>
   <sectionGroup name="Elmah">
    <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
   </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>
   <Elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <!--<errorlog type="Elmah.XmlFilerErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />-->
    <errorLog type="Elmah.MemoryErrorLog, Elmah" size="50" />
   </Elmah>
   <system.web>    
   <httpHandlers>
     <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
   </httpHandlers>    
   <httpModules>
     <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
     <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
     <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
   </httpModules>    
   </system.web>
   <system.webServer>    
   <handlers>     
     <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />           
   </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using IIS7, you need to put the handlers and modules nodes in the system.webserver node instead of system.web node.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the config entries that needs to added in web.config of the web application

```
Add under configsection
<configSections>
 <sectionGroup name="elmah">

  <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />

  <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />

  <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />

  <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />

  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

Add connectionstring section 

<connectionStrings>
<add name="elmah-express" connectionString="Data Source=[server name];Initial Catalog=  [ELMAH_customlogging];User ID=testuser;Password=Welcome1;" />

</connectionStrings>

Add elmah section just below the connectionstring section
<elmah>

<security allowRemoteAccess="0" />

<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah-express" />
</elmah>

Add handler and module entry in httphandlers and httpmodules section under system.web

<httpHandlers>

<add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>

</httpHandlers>

<httpModules>

 <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
</httpModules>

 Add handler and module entry in handlers and modules section under system.webserver

 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">



  <remove name="ErrorLog"/>

  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />

  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />

  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />

  <add name="ErrorTweet" type="Elmah.ErrorTweetModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>

  <handlers>

  <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />

  </handlers>
```

Please refer below link for elmah implementation in SharePoint

http://sidteche.blogspot.in/2014/08/implement-elmah-custom-logging-in.html